# How should the user can register himself on the website by entering invalid email-id despite of working validation code?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, security, email

I've a website in PHP. It uses MySQL database at back-end.

Let me make the scenario short and clear.

There is one user registration form present on a website. The form is submitted using AJAX. It has a field for entering user email id. The validation for this field is the domain name in an email must be '.edu', if email with other domain is entered it throws an error. For example, **anilpatil@msstate.edu** is a valid email id whereas **anilpatil@yahoo.com** is an invalid email id.

After checking the code I came to know that this validation is done in PHP and it's working fine, proper error message is displayed and the form doesn't get submit.

Even though my database is containing lot of users with email ids belonging to .com domain or some other domains. These users can login to the system as well.

Also I tried by disabling the javascript of my browser and entering invalid email id, then also it worked fine. The user couldn't register.

I'm not understanding how did these users got register? I'm not able to detect the root cause of this issue. Can someone please help me in this regard by telling me what could be the root cause of this issue?

Thanks.

P.S. :- It's not possible to put the whole lot of code here. As it's too big and comes from too many files. It's a part of a framework. But consider the validation code is working absolutely fine. My main intention is to detect the root cause for this security breach.

Comment: simple, your validation of the email address is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting any code, my best guess is people are registering themselves using your ajax file directly, and your ajax file doesn't contain the validation.

If you want me to validate it, please post your website and I will try to register directly using your ajax file

Comment: can you please check if i just added test@test.com as a new user?

Comment: what's the password for it?